# Seeing multiple events with Python watchdog library when folders are created

Tags: python, watchdog

I am having issues where I am seeing additional events that I am not expecting.

I am watching the folder `C:\Users\kvasko\Downloads\data`. If I copy a folder `2017\07\25\LogFile.xml` I will see the following 3 "created" events, when I would expect to only see 1. If I create the date folder structure ahead of time (but while the application running watching the folders) it will only generate one event like I expect. I never get an event for just a folder creation. It is like the events are being generated for the creation of the folders, but when inspecting the actual event messaged on my `on_created(self,event)` all three look events look exactly the same. What is going on here?

Here is the sample output and minimum example.

```
2017-09-22 13:58:10,182 - root - INFO - Watchdog: file created C:\Users\kvasko\Downloads\data\2017\07\25\LogFile.xml
2017-09-22 13:58:11,184 - root - INFO - Watchdog: file created C:\Users\kvasko\Downloads\data\2017\07\25\LogFile.xml
2017-09-22 13:58:12,187 - root - INFO - Watchdog: file created C:\Users\kvasko\Downloads\data\2017\07\25\LogFile.xml
```

I would expect:

```
2017-09-22 13:58:12,187 - root - INFO - Watchdog: file created C:\Users\kvasko\Downloads\data\2017\07\25\LogFile.xml
```

Is there a way to detect if its actually multiple events from folder creation?

The following is my observer configuration.

```
folder = "C:\\Users\\kvasko\\Downloads\\data"
observer = Observer(MyProcessHandler(patterns=["*.xml"]), folder, recursive=True)
observer.start_observer()

os.mkdirs("C:\\Users\\kvasko\\Downloads\\data\\2017\\07\\25")
shutil.copy2("C:\temp\LogFile.xml", "C:\\Users\\kvasko\\Downloads\\data\\2017\\07\\25")

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
except:
    print("Error")
```

The following is my handler class.

```
import logging
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

class MyProcessHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):

def on_created(self, event):
    logging.info("Watchdog: file created " + str(event.src_path))
```

Edit:

Here is a minimum working example:

```
import time
import os
import shutil
import datetime
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

class   TestEventHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        print (str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " " + str(event))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = "C:\\Temp"
    event_handler = TestEventHandler(patterns=["*.xml"])
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    os.makedirs("C:\\Temp\\2017\\07\\25")
    shutil.copy2("C:\\Temp2\\2017\\07\\25\\test.xml", "C:\\Temp\\2017\\07\\25")

    try:
       while True:
           time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
       observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Prints out:

```
2017-09-22 15:49:51.334262 <FileCreatedEvent: src_path='C:\\Temp\\2017\\07\\25\\test.xml'>
2017-09-22 15:49:52.335468 <FileCreatedEvent: src_path='C:\\Temp\\2017\\07\\25\\test.xml'>
2017-09-22 15:49:53.340998 <FileCreatedEvent: src_path='C:\\Temp\\2017\\07\\25\\test.xml'>
```

Edit2:

Change on_created() to on_any_event(). This is what was produced.

```
2017-09-23 13:14:57.288792 <FileCreatedEvent: src_path='C:\\Temp\\2017\\07\\25\\test.xml'>
2017-09-23 13:14:58.291327 <FileCreatedEvent: src_path='C:\\Temp\\2017\\07\\25\\test.xml'>
2017-09-23 13:14:59.293334 <FileCreatedEvent: src_path='C:\\Temp\\2017\\07\\25\\test.xml'>
2017-09-23 13:14:59.293334 <FileModifiedEvent: src_path='C:\\Temp\\2017\\07\\25\\test.xml'>
```

Comment: Does your copy of "LogFile.xml" tales more the two seconds?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE no, these files are like 100KB a piece.

Comment: @KevinVasko: It would be very helpful to us if you modify your code to make it a runnable example.

Comment: @KevinVasko It's weird because there are 3 events separated by 1 second from each other.

Comment: @unutbu I edited the original question and added a MWE.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Yeah, I thought that was weird too. See my edit for a MWE. I didn't add any type of delay or anything but they are almost exactly 1 second apart. It doesn't do that but only when folders are created initially it seems. If you copy a file into the `C:\\Temp\\2017\\07\\25\\` folder only 1 file is displayed. It is almost like it is getting multiple events for the creation of folders if there aren't any files in them initially. I tried working around that by putting an empty file initially and it still did the triple message.

Comment: @KevinVasko: Maybe changing `on_created` to `on_any_event` will show a more complete picture of what is going on.

Comment: @unutbu I just added that information. Looks like the only thing that was changed was that it triggered a modified event.

Comment: @KevinVasko: You might be experiencing this bug: https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/issues/346, which references [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32861420/190597). This bug seems to affect Windows and OSX; I'm not able to reproduce it on Ubuntu 14.04 with watchdog version 0.8.3, and python 3.4.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be experiencing [this bug](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/issues/346). As a workaround, you could use the `TestEventHandler` class to record the last file path created and not respond to subsequent `on_created` events 
unless the path is different than the last created path or if that path has been deleted:

```
import time
import os
import shutil
import datetime
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

class TestEventHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestEventHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.last_created = None
    def on_created(self, event):
        path = event.src_path        
        if path != self.last_created:
            print(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " " + str(event))
            self.last_created = path
    def on_deleted(self, event):
        path = event.src_path
        if path == self.last_created:
            self.last_created = None

if __name__ == '__main__':

    path = "C:\\Temp"
    target_dir = "C:\\Temp\\2017\\07\\25"
    src_dir = "C:\\Temp2\\2017\\07\\25"
    filename = 'test.xml'

    target = os.path.join(target_dir, filename)
    src = os.path.join(src_dir, filename)

    event_handler = TestEventHandler(patterns=["*.xml"])
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
        os.makedirs(target_dir)

    if os.path.exists(target):
        os.unlink(target)

    for i in range(3):
        shutil.copy2(src, target_dir)    

    try:
       while True:
           time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
       observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Comment: That looks to be the problem and your workaround works perfectly! Thanks a ton. I marked your solution as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer! I tried solving the problem in another way.

```
from functools import lru_cache
import time
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEvent
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

WATCH_DIR = "..."


def on_modified(event: FileSystemEvent):
    # Additional filtering logic etc...
    modfied_event_trigger(event.src_path)


# This value needs to be adjusted
# Caching is possible as arg is str and thus immutable
# LRU Cache is Thread Safe
@lru_cache(maxsize=256)
def modfied_event_trigger(src_path: str):
    # Inser logic here
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    patterns = ["*"]

    event_handler = PatternMatchingEventHandler(patterns, None, False, True)
    # Assign on modified
    event_handler.on_modified = on_modified

    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, WATCH_DIR, recursive=False)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
        observer.join()
```

### My rationale:

In case there are rapid successive calls, the first call will be executed. From the second call onwards, the cached value will be returned without executing the function. Thus, frequent calls will be prevented.

256 value is arbitrary. I need to try if 1 will suffice or not. Multiple different events need will be triggered, and I reserved enough space for my use case.

This is a possible solution. Worked for my use case.

**NOTE:** Noob here! This is my first answer. Apologies for anything I may have overlooked.